# Trigger.io: : Unhandled intent result

Tags: javascript, trigger.io

I am using Trigger.io to develop an application.

After using `file.getImage` and selecting an image from either the gallery or camera (on Android) I get this error message (Using trigger.io toolkit to run the app).

```
W Forge   : Unhandled intent result, should have been handled by Forge.
```

The app promptly crashes and restarts.

relevant code:

```
forge.file.getImage({}, function(file) {
    forge.request.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://example.com/upload/photo",
        files: [file],
        success: function(e) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log('failure');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on, and is this a device or the emulator?

Comment: Ok, can you send the src/config.json you're using to support@trigger.io and see if we can recreate, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the camera taking up memory on older Android devices causing it to unceremoniously shut down some apps to free up more memory.

We're working on providing more elegant handling of this situation or at least better debug output to tell you what's going on. The problem in this case was occurring on an Android 2.3 device, and could be worked around by shutting down some open apps / processes.

**Update**: we released a new foreground camera module to address this issue in our v1.4.41. platform version:
http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/camera.html#modules-camera

Comment: we can't find any modules for camera in our toolkit

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this issue on older devices too. Apparently it's a common issue on both Phonegap and Native android apps also. More can be seen on this thread:

[PhoneGap camera restarts the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368091/phonegap-camera-restarts-the-application/9524643)

The following plugin was developed for Phonegap which resolves the issue. I would be great if something like this could be developed for Trigger.io

http://code.google.com/p/foreground-camera-plugin/