# Trigger.io: forge.file.getImage() causes an application crash when accessing Android's Photo Library

Tags: android-camera, android-gallery, trigger.io

We have a serious problem in our application. Before, when we get an Image using camera or via Photo Library, our application crashed and restarts and become a blocker in our development.

`W Forge   : Unhandled intent result, should have been handled by Forge.`

We tried the solution here: [Trigger.io: : Unhandled intent result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618734/trigger-io-unhandled-intent-result)

And luckily, it won't crash now if we will use the camera. But the problem still exists when the user chooses Gallery.

Do we have any alternative way how to handle this kind of situation?

Waiting for any responses, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not *really* at the moment - the device is running low on memory and your app is being killed when the gallery starts up.

One option would be to use a plugin / module like [this](https://github.com/trigger-corp/plugin-multi-image-select), which presents the image-picking interface inside your app.

That plugin I linked to, however, is pretty old and made for Trigger.io version 1.4: it will take a bit of work to convert to a module.