# Other way to capture photo android app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm succesfully develop app with ionic+angularjs. My only problem is to take photo from camera or gallery, because, as you now, there's a problem with a lot of low profile android phone (phonegap plugin camera).
So my question is: is there any other way to upload photo from camera or gallery to a server?!

Answer (score 0):

you're gonna have to use two diffrent plugins. the camera plugin for taking a photo(gallery/camera) and the file-transfer plugin.take a look at both plugins for ionic:

FileTransfer - http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Camera - http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/

shorty what you're gonna want to do is to take a photo from the camera, store it and then upload it.

Comment: There are problems with this plugin! When you take photo from camera or from gallery, the app force to close if the phone is not performance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273429/phonegap-camera-android-kills-cordova

Comment: I had a rich experience with this plugin. works absolutely fine.

Comment: I recive a lot of comment from app users with old phone that have crash of app while tryng upload from gallery or camera! For me and other new phone all works fine!

Comment: What kind of old phones?