# Cordova app restart after getting picture from capture or photo Librairie

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

i'm trying to add picture on my server with jquery mobile and php on a cordova project for android.

When i select a picture from my librairie or i make a capture, the app restart instead of refreshing my form with the picture.

here is my html code:

```
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button>
```

here is my jquery mobile code:

```
function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        targetWidth: 600,
        targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType:navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
}

function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        targetWidth: 600,
        targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType:navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        sourceType: source
    });
}
```

I've searched everywhere but i can't find any solution.

EDIT, i have the last version of cordova and the last of file plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By luck, i've tried to change the html code, just in case, and here is the solution:

I just change this code:

```
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>
```

to this:

```
<a href="" class="ui-btn" onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</a>
```

Don't use html buttons tag, use anchor tag... don't know why but this worked !!!

Comment: i can't accept my own answer untill two days, strange :(